# Least Squares Regression for Probability Density function but I get incorrect dimensions error

Tags: matlab, least-squares

I'm trying to perform least-squares regression to this probability density function but I get prompted to perform `.*` operation in matlab instead of the standard `*` operation in evaluating `Astar`. When I do this, I get weird flat lines on the bottom part of my plot.

The code:

```
N = 10000;
mu = 5; sigma = 2;
r = randn(N,1);
x = mu+sigma*r;
bin=mu-6*sigma:0.5:mu+6*sigma;
f=hist(x,bin);
plot(bin,f,'bo'); hold on;
xlabel('bin');
ylabel('f');

y_ = f;
x_ = bin;


H = [ones(length(y_),1),x_'];
Astar = inv(H'*H)*H'.*y_;        % Line in Question
% Astar = inv(H'*H)*H'*y_;       % Initial form, but Matlab prompts to perform .* instead
Ytilde = H*Astar;
plot(x_,Ytilde, 'r-','LineWidth',1)
```

Resulting Plot:

[image]

What could be the reason?

Comment: Have you looked at what `.*` means? What can you deduce with that info? Did you check that the arrays you are trying to multiply together have dimensions that are consistent with matrix multiplication?

Comment: The tag [tag:matlab-guide] is for questions related to the MATLAB GUI development tool. Please read the tag's description before using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better or for worse, some of MATLAB's commands return row vectors, and some return column vectors. Often (or perhaps almost always) statistics is done with vectors of observations being column vectors. As far as I know, this is just something one has to be careful of when using certain commands.

Your issue comes from the fact that `y_` is a row vector, whereas normal statistic formulas suppose it is a column vector. In the 'line in question', if you use `*y_'` instead of `.*y_` (i.e. `Astar = inv(H'*H)*H'*y_';`) that gives you the expected behaviour.

The colon operator in MATLAB generates a row vector, and `hist` does the same thing. These are the root of the problem. These can be resolved in a few ways.

One way would be to transpose them when they are produced in the first part of your code. Another way would be to transpose them when you instantiate `x_` and `y_` (done below). Another way (and probably the worst way) would be to leave them as row vectors and transpose them each time you use them. Overall the solution would depend on the rest of your code, and it would be best to keep it consistent.

===

```
N = 10000;
mu = 5; sigma = 2;
r = randn(N,1);
x = mu+sigma*r;
bin=mu-6*sigma:0.5:mu+6*sigma;
f=hist(x,bin);
figure;
scatter(bin,f); hold on;
xlabel('bin');
ylabel('f');

y_ = f';
x_ = bin';


H = [ones(length(y_),1),x_];
Astar = inv(H'*H)*H'*y_;        % Line in Question
Ytilde = H*Astar;
plot(x_,Ytilde, 'r-','LineWidth',1)
```

===

[Also note that you still get a horizontal line, but y ~= 200. This is expected given the curve is symmetric, and this also agrees with MATLAB's inbuilt `polyfit` and `polyval` functions.]

[Also note that `hist` is no longer recommended.]